# Add/Embed Instagram Posts To Laravel 7

Tags: php, instagram, embed, laravel-7

**What I want:** I am creating a blog using Laravel 7 for my client. He wants to add a section containing a link to his Instagram posts by something similar to a carousel, so that, when he posts a new Instagram post the website will be automatically updated.

**What I did:**

1. I went to *developers.facebook.com*, created a new app and setup Instagram Basic Display [image: This Picture] where I got Instagram App Id, Secret and Name.
2. Added Client OAuth Settings to be for localhost, it forced me to add ssl (https) I know this won't work, I will change it to the actual domain later, and I hope for a way to test that on localhost too. [image: OAuth].
3. I added the Instagram tester and authorized it and generated an access token.[image: Tester Token]
4. I installed `composer require dymantic/laravel-instagram-feed` from [github-repo](https://github.com/Dymantic/laravel-instagram-feed)
5. I ran the command `php artisan vendor:publish` which showed me these options

```
Which provider or tag's files would you like to publish?:
  [0 ] Publish files from all providers and tags listed below
  [1 ] Provider: Dymantic\InstagramFeed\InstagramFeedServiceProvider
  [2 ] Provider: Facade\Ignition\IgnitionServiceProvider
```

So I entered `1` the I ran `php artisan migrate`; which created the following file **I updated the client id and secret to the data shown in the first photo I linked**:

```
// config/instagram-feed.php

<?php

return [
    /*
     * The client_id from registering your app on Instagram
     */
    'client_id'           => 'YOUR INSTAGRAM CLIENT ID',

    /*
     * The client secret from registering your app on Instagram,
     * This is not the same as an access token.
     */
    'client_secret'       => 'YOUR INSTAGRAM CLIENT SECRET',

    /*
     * The route that will respond to the Instagram callback during the OAuth process.
     * Only enter the path without the leading slash. You need to ensure that you have registered
     * a redirect_uri for your instagram app that is equal to combining the
     *  app url (from config) and this route
     */
    'auth_callback_route' => 'instagram/auth/callback',

    /*
     * On success of the OAuth process you will be redirected to this route.
     * You may use query strings to carry messages
     */
    'success_redirect_to' => 'instagram-auth-success',

    /*
     * If the OAuth process fails for some reason you will be redirected to this route.
     * You may use query strings to carry messages
     */
    'failure_redirect_to' => 'instagram-auth-failure'

    /*
     * You may filter out video media types by setting this to true. Carousel media
     * will become the first image in the carousel, and if there are no images, then
     * the entire carousel will be ignored.
     */
     'ignore_video' => false,

    /*
     * You may set an email address below if you wish to be notified of errors when
     * attempting to refresh the Instagram feed.
     */
    'notify_on_error' => null,
];
```

6. I added the following trait after running the command `php artisan instagram-feed:profile my-insta-username`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use \Dymantic\InstagramFeed\Profile;

trait Instagram
{
    public static function feed()
    {
        $profile = Profile::where('username', 'my-insta-username')->first();

        $feed = $profile->feed();
        
        dd($profile);
    }
}
```

**Result and Conclusion:** Obviously this didn't work, function `$profile->feed();` is unknown since the profile would be only a collection we don't have access to the Instagram API yet.

**Question:** Any idea to get the needed data how can I benefit from what I already did, even if I can get the same result using a `curl` request it would be fine??

**THANK YOU :)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want to achieve is to embed your Ig feed images into a carousel I'd recommend you to use `postaddic/instragram` package (https://github.com/postaddictme/instagram-php-scraper).

With this package you can easily fetch the URL of the image like so:

```
$instagram  = Instagram::withCredentials('login', 'password', new Psr16Adapter('Files'));
$instagram->login();
$instagram->saveSession();

$posts  = $instagram->getFeed();

foreach ($posts as $post){
    echo $post->getImageHighResolutionUrl()."\n";
}
```

If you want to test, I found this was the simplest method for fetching public accounts:

```
$instagram = new \InstagramScraper\Instagram();

// For getting information about account you don't need to auth:

$account = $instagram->getAccount('neymarjr');
```

If the profile is public even better since you can use methods that dont require your credentials for authentication.

The hassle from embbeding photos directly from Ig API is not required.

Comment: Can't I do that without login, after all the the instagram account I am fetching the feed of is a business account- which is the account of the owner of the website

Comment: Also the users might be logged  on to their account this might mess-up the session

Comment: if it is a private account you just need to pass your credentials with `$instagram = \InstagramScraper\Instagram::withCredentials('username', 'password');
$instagram->login();` . Please find out the documentation from the package. Your users don't need to use their credentials.Only you as owner of the app will have to pass the credentials (preferably via env) and you will fetch the images without problem.

Comment: This repo doesn't explain how to install `Class 'Phpfastcache\Helper\Psr16Adapter'` so I am having the message `Class 'Phpfastcache\Helper\Psr16Adapter' not found` even after I added the using statement `use Phpfastcache\Helper\Psr16Adapter;`

Comment: Also I am having the message `Too few arguments to function InstagramScraper\Instagram::withCredentials()` when I run `instagram = \InstagramScraper\Instagram::withCredentials('username', 'password'); $instagram->login();` only

Comment: try out this in your index/view function from the webpage `$medias = $instagram->getMedias('neymarjr', 20);
        $media = $medias[0]->imageStandardResolutionUrl;
        dd ($medias[0]->shortCode, $medias[0]->caption, $media);` you should get this as result from die dumping the response `"CGX0IsvpVEN"
"""
Muito feliz de te (RE)encontrar irmão! //...
"""
"https://instagram.fgdl3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s1080x1080/121697235_631985174350487_166451575622137240_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram //...`

Comment: are you passing YOUR credentials as arguments of this method? like so: `instagram = \InstagramScraper\Instagram::withCredentials('YOURusername', 'YOURpassword');`

Comment: the `getAccountByUsername()` method is the simplest form to get public profile information: try to dd this `$instagram = new \InstagramScraper\Instagram();

// For getting information about account you don't need to auth:

$account = $instagram->getAccount('neymarjr');` https://github.com/postaddictme/instagram-php-scraper/blob/master/examples/getAccountByUsername.php

Comment: The neymar way worked; BUT I am having this message `Cannot access protected property InstagramScraper\Model\Media::$imageStandardResolutionUrl`; HOWEVER `dd($medias`) is working fine `array:1 [▼
  0 => InstagramScraper\Model\Media {#1410 ▶}
]` And I can manually see all links

Comment: This worked `$media = $medias[0];       dd($media['imageThumbnailUrl']);` Thank you this way is the best answer

Comment: You've got to make the property `public`. Go to `Media class` look for that property and change it from `protected` to `public`. The package works as intended, keep playing with the most suitable option for you. There's examples for each one. Glad I helped you out.

Comment: Much Appreciated Thanks I marked this answer as correct